# zero value not checking in sql table

Tags: php, sql

My table name cart. it have three columns `p_id , ip_add , qty`. if I want check `qty=0` then print a message "select quantity". otherwise it will redirect another page "checkout.php". my database connection is okkk. anyone can give enter code hereme some suggestion for run it. my code is:
I also tried `$q=o;`
and in sql query

select * from cart where qty like $q;

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['checkout'])) 
    {
    global $conn;
    $check="SELECT * FROM `cart` WHERE `qty` = 0";
    $run_check=mysqli_query($conn,$check);
    if($run_check) 
    {
    echo "<script> alert('Select Quantity & click on update');
    window.location.href='cart.php';
    </script>";
    }
    else{
    echo "<script>
    window.location.href='checkout.php';
    </script>";
    }
    }
    ?>
```

in present in my table in qty column have 2 values 2 , 5 but its not checking and showing 1st message "Select Quantity & click on update".
but not redirect to checkout.php.
please solve my problems and give me right suggestion.

Comment: `mysqli_query()` returns true\false\object, not the actual result of the query https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Now tell me what will use place of mysqli_query ???